# Get logged user's username, id etc in Composite C1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c1-cms

How to get info about logged user in my controller (MVC Player) in composite c1?

Answer (score 1):

As you were doing in normal asp.net application do the same trick

To Get the user name

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```